Getting error 42601 while creating table in PostgreSQL
Hello here is the code that i was trying to run on the server.
CREATE TABLE flashcards (
    id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    question VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    answer TEXT NOT NULL,
    created TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP NOT NULL
);
```[Here is the screenshot to the error](https://i.sstatic.net/JPVOdx2C.png)



I am expecting a table created in a similar way as mentined above with id being auto-incremented and primary.


Please post the error message as text, not a link to a painting of it. You can [edit] your question to include it as formatted text.

AUTO_INCREMENT, that's not valid syntax.

AUTO_INCREMENT is not present in postgres use serial instead of it.SERIAL does the same job of AUTO_INCREMENT.
CREATE TABLE flashcards (
    id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    question VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    answer TEXT NOT NULL,
    created TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP NOT NULL
);


Thanks it did worked perfectly fine as i wanted. I am completely new to postgres so i was not aware of it. Anyways Thank you again for solving my problem

That is why there is documentation CREATE TABLE.

The better answer would be to use the SQL standard generated as identity.
